# Rails datatables ajax json 414 request URI too large

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, datatables

So I've tried the [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables) tutorial, as well as the one for the [ajax-datatables-rails](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ajax-datatables-rails/0.0.1/frames) gem. I'm creating a list of clients from a database--not users. I believe I've narrowed it down to the fact that when using the `GET` method via Datatables' `sServerMethod`, I receive a 414 with "**Request-URI too large**". When I use the `POST` method, I simply get null values for all attributes except `id` which makes sense since the POST json is used for creating a client. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code and diagnostics response:

```
// custom.js    
$("#datatable").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": $('#datatable').data('source'),
    });
```

Response:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3001/clients.json
Request-URI Too Large
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to fix the error by installing the gem **thin**.

Add this line to your `Gemfile` if you are having this issue:

```
gem 'thin'
```

Comment: Looks like the reason is because WEBrick server can't handle the request, but the Thin server has no problem. Thanks!